Growth of factorial functions and tetration
Good morning everyone, I have a doubt about the growth rate of the following two functions:
$$ \operatorname f(x)=x! $$
and
$$ \operatorname g(x)=^x n,\quad\mbox{where}\ \quad n \in \mathbb{R^+} $$
I was wondering which of the two grow faster, so I thought I'd formalize the question as:
$$ \lim_{x\to + \infty}{\frac{^x n}{x!}=1} $$
Does it exist and what values ​​can $n$ take for the above relationship to be true?
Hoping my question makes sense
Thank you

Not an answer but I would think of trying to take log and then use Stirling's approximation.

I think when $n>\root e\of e$ tetration grows faster than factorials.

@Sounak Are you referring to a natural logarithm or perhaps a super logarithm?

@Lucenaposition What makes you think that value might be?
